# renaming a file in unix using a variable

Tags: unix

I have a script that will generate output.txt . Now I want to rename this output.txt . I need to rename this file with a variable. Eg: I have an input file from which i get values and store it in a temp variable. Now i want to rename this output.txt with this temp value.
I was able to do it with the following command. But i see some special character getting appended to the file name.

I need to rename output.txt with `Type` value.

```
#!/bin/sh
mv result/$bld_no/output.txt "result/$bld_no/$Type"
```

I am able to rename the file but an extra character is appended.
`A1XFE4LQM16OSW`   ( the box is a question mark when i see from console)

Can anyone please let me know how to rename a file with a variable name without adding any special character to it?

Comment: It's probably in the `Type` variable, looks like maybe a carriage-return. If you're reading this var from a file, you probable need to strip it of trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the issue is actually a "special" character at the end of the variable.

Here's what I'd do, assuming you are using bash,

```
TYPE="${TYPE%?}"
```

which will strip the last character off the variable.

I'd also suggest investigating how you are setting TYPE in the first place, but that's not an answer to your question.

Comment: Hi, the variable doesn't have any special character.The variable only contains "A1XFE4LQM16OSW". But on trying to rename, that is         mv result/$bld_no/output.txt "result/$bld_no/$Type"    renames the output.txt with a special character at the end.